# I've come across IBAN & SWIFT numbers of a large international healthcare organization (in a publicly accessible document). Anything I should do?

Tags: fraud, swift, iban

A little more detail.

I was searching a European health authority website for documents related to a specific healthcare conglomerate.

I've done this many times in the past (looking for regulatory data).

This time, one of the documents that I downloaded contains contact information, addresses, phone numbers, IBAN, and SWIFT/BIC numbers for the conglomerate.

I've never seen this type of information in a publicly facing document, but I'm wondering if I'm being too paranoid, or if there is someone I should alert.

Thank you.

Comment: In countries where IBAN is used it's fairly common to publish the payments account details for people to pay directly from their bank accounts. If you're from the US that would look weird, but that's because the American banking system is weird, not the rest of the world's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither IBAN nor SWIFT numbers are secret information, they merely allow people to send money to those identified bank accounts and not to withdraw money from them.

If there is personal data of individuals in the addresses and phone numbers then this could be a GDPR breach and you could report it as such - in the UK you would do this [to the institution directly in the first instance, and then to the Information Commissioners Office](https://ico.org.uk/for-the-public/how-to-make-a-data-protection-complaint/) if you're not satisfied with their response. I am not sure what the equivalent processes are in the EU for how to report breaches but probably similar.